# Java Chess King

Tags: java, chess

I have all my other pieces moving without a hitch, but the King is moving and is able to move more than one place at a time which anyone who understands chess understands that is wrong can anyone help?

This is my King Code

```
    else if(pieceName.contains("King")){
    int newY = e.getY()/75;
    int newX = e.getX()/75;         
    boolean inTheWay = false;       
    int distance = Math.abs(startX-newX);


    if(((newX < 0) || (newX > 7))||((newY < 0)||(newY > 7))){
        validMove = false;          
    }
    else{

        validMove = true;               

        //Check if the move is a diagonal move

        if(Math.abs(startX-newX)==Math.abs(startY-newY))
        {
            // If there are any pieces along the diagonal in the way the move cannot be made.
            if((startX-newX < 0)&&(startY-newY < 0)){
                for(int i=0; i < distance;i++){
                    if(piecePresent((initialX+(i*75)), (initialY+(i*75)))){
                        inTheWay = true;
                    }
                }                       
            }
            else if((startX-newX < 0)&&(startY-newY > 0)){
                for(int i=0; i < distance;i++){
                    if(piecePresent((initialX+(i*75)), (initialY-(i*75)))){                     
                        inTheWay = true;
                    }
                }                       
            }
            else if((startX-newX > 0)&&(startY-newY > 0)){
                for(int i=0; i < distance;i++){
                    if(piecePresent((initialX-(i*75)), (initialY-(i*75)))){
                        inTheWay = true;
                    }
                }                       
            }
            else if((startX-newX > 0)&&(startY-newY < 0)){
                for(int i=0; i < distance;i++){
                    if(piecePresent((initialX-(i*75)), (initialY+(i*75)))){
                        inTheWay = true;
                    }
                }                       
            }                                       
            if(inTheWay){
                validMove = false;
            }
            else{
                if(piecePresent(e.getX(), (e.getY()))){
                    if(pieceName.contains("White")){
                        if(checkWhiteOponent(e.getX(), e.getY())){
                            validMove = true;
                        }
                        else{
                            validMove = false;
                        }
                    }
                    else{
                        if(checkBlackOponent(e.getX(), e.getY())){
                            validMove = true;
                        }
                        else{
                            validMove = false;
                        }
                    }                                               
                }
                else{
                    validMove = true;
                }                                               
            }                                       
        }
        else if(((Math.abs(startX-newX)!=0)&&(Math.abs(startY-newY) == 0))|| ((Math.abs(startX-newX)==0)&&(Math.abs(newY-startY)!=0)))
        {
            if(Math.abs(startX-newX)!=0){
                //we have movement along the x axis
                int xMovement = Math.abs(startX-newX);
                if(startX-newX > 0){
                    //movement in the left direction....
                    for(int i=0;i < xMovement;i++){
                        if(piecePresent(initialX-(i*75), e.getY())){
                            inTheWay = true;
                            break;
                        }
                        else{
                            inTheWay = false;
                        }
                    }                           
                }
                else{
                    for(int i=0;i < xMovement;i++){                             
                        if(piecePresent(initialX+(i*75), e.getY())){
                            inTheWay = true;
                            break;
                        }
                        else{
                            inTheWay = false;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            else{
                //we have movement along the y axis
                int yMovement = Math.abs(startY-newY);
                    if(startY-newY > 0){
                        //movement in the left direction....
                        for(int i=0;i < yMovement;i++){                                 
                            if(piecePresent(e.getX(),initialY-(i*75))){
                                inTheWay = true;
                                break;
                            }
                            else{
                                inTheWay = false;
                            }
                        }                           
                    }
                    else{
                        for(int i=0;i < yMovement;i++){
                            if(piecePresent(e.getX(),initialY+(i*75))){
                                inTheWay = true;
                                break;
                            }
                            else{
                                inTheWay = false;
                            }
                        }
                    }
            }
            if(inTheWay){
                validMove = false;
            }
            else{
                if(piecePresent(e.getX(), (e.getY()))){
                    if(pieceName.contains("White")){
                        if(checkWhiteOponent(e.getX(), e.getY())){
                            validMove = true;
                        }
                        else{
                            validMove = false;
                        }
                    }
                    else{
                        if(checkBlackOponent(e.getX(), e.getY())){
                            validMove = true;
                        }
                        else{
                            validMove = false;
                        }
                    }                                               
                }
                else{
                    validMove = true;
                }
            }
        }               
        else{ // the move that is being tried is not a diagonal move...
            validMove = false;
        }               
    }   

}
```

Comment: Have you run your code step-by-step under debugger?

Comment: Are you checking that newX is within 1 either side of startX and newY is within 1 either side of startY (unless a castling move is being performed)?

Comment: It's not reporting any error in the app, it is just moving as if its a queen

Comment: Would you like to post more code?

Comment: For starters, `if(Math.abs(startX-newX)==Math.abs(startY-newY))` will return true if `delta(X) == delta(Y)` which could be `>1`

Comment: You've got a ton of code redundancy and an excessively long method. I'm not sure how you can keep track of what is happening logically based on that code. You should consider refactoring that code including creating methods and calling them, as doing this will make the code safer, easier to debug and easier to enhance later. In fact, I just noticed that that code wall is not even the complete method.

Comment: What is up with the 75 multiplier?

Comment: @The111: that's one of several *magic* numbers that also should be refactored away.

Comment: That was something we were given by our lecturer I did not fully understand why he had that in

Comment: My guess is that is the number of pixels wide for a chess board square - maybe a calculation from the mouse click position?

Comment: @ConorDas never run code you don't fully understand, and expect it to do something that you do understand. ;-)

Comment: @Jason good guess, sounds right.

Comment: I highly recommend separating out the "model" code - the code that deals with where everything is on the board and how it can move - from the code that deals with drawing the board on the screen and handling events from the GUI.  Right now, you've got the two mixed up together, and it will make your code very hard to maintain.

Comment: Yes I can see when i have everything together it is a bit harder to navigate through the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the king is not performing the castling move then:

- `newX` must equal either `startX` or `startX+1` or `startX-1`
- `newY` must equal either `startY` or `startY+1` or `startY-1`

If castling, the king must be in its initial position, and it can only move to one of two positions.